# error of "Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account"

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, anchor-spl

I am trying to create an ATA using this but i get this error

```
#[account(
init,
payer = signer,
seeds = [rent_manager.key().as_ref()],
bump,
token::mint = pay_mint,
token::authority = rent_manager,
)]
pub rent_manager_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

[image]

Comment: Please copy the logs and paste the text instead of an image.

Answer (score 2):

An associated token account [by definition](https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account#finding-the-associated-token-account-address) already uses its own set of seeds. Try removing the `seeds` constraint and see if that helps. And update to using the correct associated token constraints:

```
#[account(
    init,
    payer = payer,
    associated_token::mint = mint,
    associated_token::authority = payer,
)]
pub token: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was due to i was using wrong seeds for *rent_manager_vault*

Answer (score 0):

To create an associated token account you need to pass ATA program ID and use the anchor_spl crate with associated_token.

```
use anchor_spl::{associated_token::AssociatedToken}

....

   #[account(
    init_if_needed,
    payer = signer,
    associated_token::mint = pay_mint,
    associated_token::authority = rent_manager,
    )]
    rent_manager_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    ...

    associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
```

Comment: This wont work as ATA is a PDA an it wont work with custom seeds

Comment: Oh yes makes sense